# How to parse mongodb log to gain the most time consuming queries in a day?

Tags: mongodb, shell, logging

I am looking for a solution to gain the top ten queries in a day (the most time consuming queries in a day) , I want to create a shell script in Linux and 
parse the MongoDB log , I don't know , is this the best way to find the most time consuming queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have developed some scripts ,but there is very efficient tool to analyze mongodb log , you can download mtools to take advantage of powerful reports based on python packages .
have the following link 
https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools/

BR,

Comment: Can you please share the link to the tool you mention? This makes it easier for people to follow your solution. Thanks!